# How to use Node.js to create modified versions of html documents?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do this:

1. Read html document "myDocument.html" with Node
2. Insert contents of another html document named "foo.html" immediately after the open body tag of myDocument.html.
3. Insert contents of yet another html document named "bar.html" immediately before the close body tag of myDocument.html.
4. Save the modified version of "myDocument.html".

To do the above, I would need to search the DOM with Node to find the open and closing body tags.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, you can use the native Filesystem module that comes with Node.JS. (`var fs = require("fs")`). This allows you to read and convert the HTML to a string, perform string replace functions, and finally save the file again by rewriting it.

The advantage is that this solution is completely native, and requires no external libraries. It is also completely faithful to the original HTML file.

```
//Starts reading the file and converts to string.
fs.readFile('myDocument.html', function (err, myDocData) {
      fs.readFile('foo.html', function (err, fooData) { //reads foo file
          myDocData.replace(/\<body\>/, "<body>" + fooData); //adds foo file to HTML
          fs.readFile('bar.html', function (err, barData) { //reads bar file
              myDocData.replace(/\<\/body\>/, barData + "</body>"); //adds bar file to HTML
              fs.writeFile('myDocumentNew.html', myDocData, function (err) {}); //writes new file.
          });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple but not accurate way, you can do this:

```
str = str.replace(/(<body.*?>)/i, "$1"+read('foo.html'));

str = str.replace(/(<\/body>)/i, read('bar.html')+'$1');
```

It will not work if the myDocument content contains multiple "<body ..' or '</body>', e.g. in javascript, and also the foo.html and bar.html can not contains '$1' or '$2'...

If you can edit the content of myDocument, then you can leave some "placeholder" there(as html comments), like

```
<!--foo.html-->
```

Then, it's easy, just replace this "placeholder" .

Comment: I am required to link to this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) library, which has a simplified jQuery-ish API.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var dom = cheerio(myDocumentHTMLString);
dom('body').prepend(fooHTMLString);
dom('body').append(barHTMLString);
var finalHTML = dom.html();
```

And just to be clear since the legions of pro-regex individuals are already appearing in droves, yes you need a real parser. No you cannot use a regular expression. Read Stackoverflow  lead developer [Jeff Atwood's post on parsing HTML the Cthulhu way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: Is the extra library really necessary though?

Comment: Glad you asked! http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Darn, you have the Jeff Atwood on your side there. However, seeing as only the body tag needs to be identified, I don't think a whole parsing library would be necessary as such.
Nevertheless, you may want to mention the filesystem functions, as the OP specifically mentions reading and saving the file; not just modifying the dom.

Comment: Yes but stackoverflow requires "thoroughly researched" questions and attempted code snippets. Reading files in node is clearly documented and the web is full of examples. OP has >2K rep. I think the crux of his question has to do with the HTML modification not stuff you learn in your first 90 seconds of a node.js tutorial.

Comment: Jeff doesn't appear to be on anyone's side in that post: `It's considered good form to demand that regular expressions be considered verboten, totally off limits for processing HTML, but I think that's just as wrongheaded as demanding **every trivial HTML processing task be handled by a full-blown parsing engine**. It's more important to understand the tools, and their strengths and weaknesses, than it is to knuckle under to knee-jerk dogmatism.`

Comment: I'm out. I posted my answer. I would use cheerio. If you like regexes, upvote the other answers. Please stop commenting as I don't care.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you care, since the comment was not for you. It was for other readers who might see your multiple appeals to authority and not dig deeper. I like regexes, but I also like your way. Why the hostility towards regexes. "Legions of pro-regex individuals are already appearing in droves?" Really?

Comment: `<!-- Regexes do not understand that HTML has comments and I could say <body> in here. Many versions will fail with newlines or unexpected whitespace. -->`